# Inversion bei "zwar" mit mehreren Sätzen

Tags: grammar, word-order

Wenn man

> Dieser Hut hat drei Ecken und ich vermisse einen dreieckigen Hut. Aber das ist trotzdem nicht mein Hut

mit "zwar" formulieren will, wie ist es richtig?

> Zwar hat dieser Hut drei Ecken und vermisse ich einen dreieckigen Hut, aber das ist nicht mein Hut.

oder

> Zwar hat dieser Hut drei Ecken und ich vermisse einen dreieckigen Hut, aber das ist nicht mein Hut.

? (Gewiss ginge auch

> Dieser Hut hat zwar drei Ecken und ich vermisse einen dreieckigen Hut, aber das ist nicht mein Hut.

)

Die erste Version, bei der beide Teilsätze invertiert werden, scheint mir "konsequenter", aber die zweite hört sich natürlicher an ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das "Problem" besteht darin, dass man semantisch das *zwar* auch auf den zweiten Teilsatz anwenden könnte. Das wird deutlich, wenn man die ersten beiden Teile einfach umdreht.

> Zwar vermisse ich einen dreiecken Hut und dieser Hut hat drei Ecken, aber das ist nicht mein Hut.

Daher wirkt auf den ersten Blick die Inversion akzeptabel. Warum es aber zugleich auch merkwürdig klingt, erkennt man, wenn man das *zwar* wiederholt.

> Zwar hat dieser Hut drei Ecken und zwar vermisse ich einen dreieckigen Hut, aber das ist nicht mein Hut.

Der Satz ist so eine sprachliche Katastrophe. Stattdessen kann man aber problemlos eine Phrase wie *in der Tat* verwenden:

> Zwar hat dieser Hut drei Ecken und in der Tat vermisse ich einen dreieckigen Hut, aber das ist nicht mein Hut.

Verwendet man kein Adverb, sollte man meiner Meinung nach aus stilistischen Gründen das Subjekt und das Verb nicht invertieren und dadurch eindeutig das *zwar* nur auf den ersten Teil anwenden.

Im zweiten Beispiel besteht das Problem übrigens deswegen nicht, weil *zwar* aufgrund der Positionierung nicht semantisch auf den zweiten Teil angewendet werden kann. Somit ist eine Invertierung dort sogar gänzlich falsch.

Comment: Ich glaube, das Grundproblem besteht darin, dass ein "zwar" auf ein "aber" wartet. Das anzukündigen ist ja seine einzige Bestimmung. Man kann aber nicht 2 abers ankündigen ohne das erste zwar vorher "zu schließen". Das "zwar" bezieht sich also rein syntaktisch gesehen ausschließlich auf den ersten Teil. Der "und" Satz ist extra. Man kann ihn als vom "zwar" mitüberdeckt ansehen, muss aber nicht. Ich kann das "zwar" auch ausschließlich auf den ersten Teil beziehen. Dazu kommt dann noch, dass auch der Satz "Zwar vermisse ich meinen Hut, aber das ist nicht meiner." schlecht klingt... für mich

Comment: ... ich glaube, er klingt schlecht, da beide Satzteile mit einem "leeren" ersten Block beginnen. "Zwar" heißt nix, und "das" allein heißt auch nix. Dadurch ist die Struktur unspannend. [Leeres Wort - Füllung kommt später]... , aber [leeres Wort - Füllung kommt später]. Es spielen also mehrere Aspekte zusammen und lassen das Doppel-Zwar so furchtbar klingen.

Comment: Nur um das klarzustellen - der dreieckige Hut ist natürlich nur Dummy-Inhalt. Und ich meinte es durchaus so, dass auch der zweite Teil "ge-abert" werden soll. Denkt vielleicht eher an: "Zwar stolpert Theo oft über die eigenen Füße und/oder [ihn verläßt/verläßt ihn] schon nach 30 Minuten die Kondition, aber dennoch steckt in ihm das Potenzail zu einem großen Fußballer." - Das Argument mit dem Wiederholen von "zwar" überzeugt mich (noch) nicht ganz, denn bei Konjunktionen hat man ja auch ohne Wiederholung "Obwohl dieser Hut drei Ecken hat und [obwohl] ich einen dreieckigen Hut vermisse, ..."

Comment: @Emanuel Da ist was dran. Mach doch daraus eine eigene Antwort.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen... zwar ist aber ein Kommentaradverb und keine Konjunktion. Ich hab' schon verstanden, dass du beide Teile verabern willst. Ich denke es läuft tatsächlich darauf hinaus, dass zwei "zwars" nicht nebeneinander offen sein können. Das "zwar" gilt grammatisch nur für den ersten Teil. Wir implizieren den Rest. Wenn es nicht so wäre, dann sollte sich das "zwar" auch im zweiten Teil einsetzen lassen.... quasi als Gegenteil der Weglassprobe

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen... Kommando zurück... es ist eine Eigenschaft von Adverbialen allgemein (siehe die andere Antwort)... ich kann es aber noch nicht griffig formulieren.

Answer (score 2):

Die beiden Teilsätze sind selbstständige Sätze mit jeweils eigenem Subjekt (*dieser Hut* und *ich*). Es wäre auch erlaubt, sie mit einem Komma zu trennen:

> Dieser Hut hat drei Ecken, und ich vermisse einen dreieckigen Hut.

Aus diesem Grund bezieht sich aber das *zwar* nur auf den ersten Teilsatz, und dein erster Vorschlag ist falsch oder zumindest stilistisch unschön. Grammatikalisch korrekt wäre es, wenn beide Teilsätze dasselbe Subjekt hätten:

> Zwar hat dieser Hut drei Ecken und wird von mir vermisst, aber es ist nicht meiner.

Allerdings wird dadurch natürlich der Sinn der Aussage verändert. In diesem Fall ergibt sich sogar ein logischer Widerspruch.

Comment: Das gleiche gilt übrigens für viele Adverbien... wie "trotzdem", "heute", "dort" etc...